# Are there any candidate languages in NE but not E?

Tags: complexity-classes, exp-time-algorithms, nondeterminism

Let ${\bf E}=\text{DTIME}(2^{O(n)})$ and ${\bf NE} = \text{NTIME}(2^{O(n)})$

Is there any candidate natural language being in ${\bf NE} \setminus {\bf E}$, that is, people believe is ${\bf NE}$ but not ${\bf E}$?